# GridFS MongoDB retrieve metadata when downloading files

Tags: c#, database, mongodb, gridfs, data-storage

I am trying to use GridFs for uploading and downloading the documents.

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var db = mongoClient.GetDatabase("TestDB");

Stream source = new MemoryStream(Content.ToBson());

//Initializing GdridFS conection
GridFSBucket bucket = new GridFSBucket(db);
var options = new GridFSUploadOptions
{
    ChunkSizeBytes = 64512, // 63KB
    Metadata = new BsonDocument
    {
        { "A", "1" },
        { "booleanValue", true }
    } 
};
// file name and source content we are receiving fom post man.
var id = await Bucket.UploadFromStreamAsync("FileName", source, options);
```

till here everything is fine. Now I want to download the file based on filename and id.
so I use the method.

```
var x = Bucket.DownloadAsBytesAsync(fileName);
```

Now when I downloaded it now I want to know all the information regarding the files which was present at the time of uploading. like I want to know the metadata information which I store at the point of upload also the filename, id every piece of information that was present at the time of upload but I don't know how to get it after download all the information.
Any help will be appreciated.
Regards

Comment: You should always add a version property to a database so you can track versions.

Comment: @jdweng: Do you have any idea that how i will get all the information when i download the file.

Comment: You are not downloading a file   You are getting a Database with tables and you can put the info into the tables.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.can you just give me a small example or a link where I can understand this. I am a newbie so don't have much knowledge about the topic

Comment: You can use metadata.  See : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Comment: I already use the metadata reading the document while uploading the file as you can see in my post.my question was when I will download the file in the function at that time how I will get the same meta information? That I need to figure out.please check my code as I pasted above.I am successful upload the file but when I download I need the all the information of file including object id file name and metadata.

Comment: The values are being added in the constructor as keys in a dictionary (https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDocument.htm) so use GetValue(String).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/reference/gridfs/downloadingfiles/ and https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/reference/gridfs/findingfiles/#gridfsfileinfo-class:

- Use something like https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_GridFS_GridFSBucket_1_OpenDownloadStream.htm to get a stream
- Use https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_GridFS_GridFSDownloadStream_1_FileInfo.htm to get the file info
- Use https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_GridFS_GridFSFileInfo_1_Metadata.htm to get the metadata

Comment: @Thanks for your reply. Now i understand the how we can filter data.
I have one more question regarding filtering. Suppose I want to filter based on two factors.I want to fetch based on DocType(Which is stored in metadata) and object id.
var filter = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.And(Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Metadata.GetElement("DocType").ToString(), docType.ToString()), 
          Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id.ToString(), docId));

I have written the filter as above but does not getting the correct result.Can you please point out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: You can query files collection like any other collection. I do not know c# syntax since I don't use .net.